# Does grub auto repair?

Tags: 16.04, grub2

If my Ubuntu 16.04 pc fails to boot due to a graphics driver issue, will it do something different on the next boot, such as trying to boot without the drivers?

Comment: No, it won't auto-repair. If booted again the same way, it'll fail the same way. **You** can make changes to begin to work around a failure though... like doing a `fsck` or uninstalling bad drivers, etc.

Comment: Generally when a graphics driver fails you change the grub kernel parameter to `nomodset` and if that doesn't work then to `text`... These are generalities and it depends on the graphics card and the exact problem. Luckily I've never had one so I'm just going on what I've read on this site.

Comment: Do you know why my machine might consistently alternate between boot failure and boot success then?

Comment: ah... you didn't tell us that before... when you have a boot failure, exactly what happens, when, and what do you see on your screen? Do you know how to check the syslog for errors?

Comment: When it fails, it freezes on the "Please Unlock disk sda5_crypt2" screen. If I pressed ctrl+alt+F1...F6, it will go to different ttys with a flashing prompt but nothing happens if I press enter. I don't get anything from the failed attempts if I go to syslog. I don't think it gets that far.

Comment: You've encrypted your disk/partition, and it's asking for you to enter your password. You won't see anything on the screen as you type your password, for your own security. If you've forgotten your password, you're in a whole lot of trouble. If it sometimes allows you in, you may have a file system error. Let me know, and I can tell you how to fsck it. Make sure to start new comments with `@heynnema` if you want my attention, or I may miss the comment.

Comment: It isnt failing due to the encryption. When I try to type in the password nothing happens. If I reboot and try again it lets me type in my password fine.

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer showing you how to check your file system for errors. Make sure to start new comments with `@heynnema` if you want my attention, or I may miss the comment.

Answer (score 0):

To perform a file system check...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery Mode
- choose root access
- type `sudo fsck -f /`
- run fsck more than once if there were errors
- type `reboot`